# Resources files and default list forms (SP2010)

Tags: list-form, resource-files, resources

I have a feature that provisions fields, a content type, and a list based on that content type (all programmatically)

To implement localization, I set the title of the SPFieldLink objects to a resource string in the format "$Resources:mybundle,key" before adding them to my content type.

When I browse to the list, I see the columns correctly translated to the current language. However, when I add or view a list item, the labels always show in english, even though the rest of the forms (such as the buttons and the ribbon) are properly translated.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear the the SPFieldLink object doesn't support localization in the same way that lists or SPFields do.

I 'solved' this issue by setting the title of the SPFields directly, before creating the SPFieldLink.